# Example of charts on $\mathbb{R}$ that are $\mathcal{C}^r$ compatible but not $\mathcal{C}^{r+1}$ compatible.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

Is there a simple example of two charts where this is the case? I'm struggling to think up one.

Comment: Try finding a $C^r$ diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ that is not $C^{r+1}$ - this should be doable with a piecewise polynomial. Then compare with the identity chart.

Comment: Take one map to be the identity map. Let the other one be $x \to x^k sin(1/x)$. Choose $k$ appropriately. Does it work (in a sufficiently small neighborhood of origin?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Anthony Carapetis's comment, let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}x &\text{if $x\leq 0$}\\ x+x^{r+1}&\text{if $x>0$}\end{cases}$.  These are both homeomorphisms, and $f^{-1}\circ g=g$ is $C^r$ but not $C^{r+1}$, with nonvanishing derivative everywhere (as long as $r>0$).  So they are compatible as $C^r$ charts on $\mathbb{R}$, but not as $C^{r+1}$ charts.